# Custom control losing size around edge when added to form

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, custom-controls, custom-component

Having some issues with creating a simple control in vb.net.

I create a control with a single label in, I don't change anything except the colour of the control and the label and also making the label anchor to the edges ( with a small border around the edge)

When i then build it and add this control to a form. Some of the edges are cut off and it isn't anchored the way it was in the control.

I have added images to explain:

so first i create the label:
http://postimage.org/image/5e4fmtmb9/

and now when i add it to the form:
http://postimage.org/image/8okm932cb/

as you can see in the second image the control has lost its white border at the right and bottom. Can anyone please explain this? I thought it might have been because of font changes but I haven't changed the font?

I eventually want to make a control kind of like this: postimage.org/image/3wn5t62ix/ with white space around the labels.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the BorderStyle of the `UserControl` in design mode to "None".  It's interfering with the sizes of the controls when using Anchors.

When the compiled control is on the form, set the border property there, the label inside it will adjust correctly then.

Otherwise, in design mode of the `UserControl`, you will have to adjust the size of the labels by subtracting their widths by the total size of the borders.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend Glad it works.  In place of kudos, feel free to use the controls to the left of answers to accept them when they solve the problem.  Also, feel free to vote up any useful questions or answers you find helpful.